# PHP how to call included file functions

Tags: php, function, call

lets say i make a file **Services.php**

```
<?php

$myGlobalVar='ranSTR';

function serv1($num)
{
   //some processing...
   return $num;
}

function serv2($num)
{
   //some processing...
   return $num;
}

?>
```

and i include it in some other file lets say **myFile.php** by

```
include "Services.php";
```

OR

```
require "Services.php";
```

- How can i call its functions in **myFile.php**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can just call any of these functions. After the file is included, the functions will be placed in the global scope.

have you not tried:

```
include "Services.php";

$num = 123;

serv1($num);
```

From the doc:

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

Check out these two doc resources for more information on what you're having trouble understanding:

- include statement: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
- variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I tried this but I keep getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function

Comment: Sorry, I found the problem I was requiring the page like so:  require("http://localhost/path/to/required/file.php");

Answer (score 5):

Just call them the same as you would any other function:

```
serv1(42);
```

Answer (score 5):

You should just be able to call `serv2(3)` or whatever need be.